# Lua Naming a table from function input

Tags: function, lua

If I do something wrong with the formatting or anything else, sorry, I don't use this site often.

I'm trying to make a function in lua that with take a name I give it, and create a subtable with that name, and when I tried something like this it just made the absolute name I put in the function's code.

```
NewSubtable =
function(SubtableName)
    Table.SubtableName = {} --Creates a subtable called SubtableName
end
```

How can I make this create a subtable that is called by the name I give in the function when I use it? Is there an indicator or something to let the code know not to use the name given, but to use the variable assigned when I use the function?

*EDIT: So whenever I try this, I get the the result "table index is nil" and it points to the error on line 4*

I went and tested this but with a different input type, and it was just my fault. I didn't think that strings would the the value type you'd need for what I'm doing. My problem is solved.

Complete code:

```
Items = {}

NewWeapon = function(id, name, desc, minDMG, maxDMG)
    Items[id] = {}
    Items[id].Name = name
    Items[id].Desc = desc
    Items[id].MinDMG = minDMG
    Items[id].MaxDMG = maxDMG
end

NewWeapon(Test, "test", "test", 1, 1)
```

Comment: `Table[SubtableName] = {}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Table.SubtableName` is actually a syntactic sugar for  `Table['SubtableName']`.  To use the contents of variable SubtableName use the idom `Table[SubtableName]`.

Comment: Welcome! Enclose text in backticks to show it as code.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  I already wondered how I can mark code!  And a good 2017 to you!

Comment: Whenever I try to make a table with that way of typing it, I get the error "table index is nil" and I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Please show a xcomplete sample code that gives you that nil message, I am sure we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Alright, it's not much code so it shouldn't be a problem. I really don't know much, just some simple stuff and since I've been stuck on this I haven't gotten far.

Comment: I figured it out, it was just the way I was using the function. This was, once again, just due to my little knowledge. Thanks for the help.